# How to get Customizable Options of a simple product in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, adminhtml, custom-options, simple-product

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');

$customOptions = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProdu

ctOptionCollection($product);

print_r($customOptions);
```

I have created a customizable option, Option Title named as Colors and used the above code, but it didn't return any value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the correct answer..
In your phtml page,

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product


foreach ($product->getOptions() as $options) {

                $optionData = $options->getValues();
                foreach ($optionData as $data) {
                    print_r($data->getData());
                    echo   $optionPrice[] = $data->getPrice();
                   echo $optionDuration[] = $data->getTitle();
                }
            }
```

Comment: How do you get the option selected of that product

Comment: Hi Rakesh, If i have a customizable options for a product then how do i add a custom css class

Answer (score 5):

First of: don't directly use the Object Manager, but use dependency injection instead.

Secondly, for this task you have a Service Contract that's specific for this purpose: the `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductCustomOptionRepositoryInterface`. You can use the `getList()`-method of this service contract to get a list of options.

Example code:

```
class Example {
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductCustomOptionRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customOptionRepository;

    /**
     * Example constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductCustomOptionRepositoryInterface $customOptionRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductCustomOptionRepositoryInterface $customOptionRepository
    )
    {
        $this->customOptionRepository = $customOptionRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $sku
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface[]
     */
    public function getCustomOptions(string $sku): array
    {
        return $this->customOptionRepository->getList($sku);
    }
}
```

Comment: Placed this code in my custom module block and in my custom phtml page,  placed echo $this->getCustomOptions(); to get result. But a fatal error occur for this.

Comment: What was the fatal error?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you have found the way to get Customizable option of simple product, but I found out how to get the option that have selected. Using this code below:

```
    public function getCustomizableOption($item) {
        /**
         * @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface
         */
        $product = $item->getProduct();
        $options = $product->getOptions();
        $responseData = [];
        $optionIds = explode(',',$product->getCustomOptions()['option_ids']->getData('value'));
        $optionTypeIds = [];
        foreach ($optionIds as $id) {
            array_push($optionTypeIds,$product->getCustomOptions()['option_'.$id]->getData('value'));
        }
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            $optionData = $option->getValues();
            foreach ($optionData as $data) {
                if (in_array($data->getData('option_type_id'),$optionTypeIds)) {
                    array_push($responseData,array('label' => $product->getData('options')[$i++]->getData('title'), 'value' => $data->getData('title')));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return $responseData;
    }
```

Hope it will help someone who want to get the selected option.